# Angular update in one project to higher version than on machine

Tags: angular

On my computer I have Angular 8. In one project I want to have version 9. How to update Angular to version 9 only in this one project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your project repository is

```
c:\repos\myproject
```

Using cmd or Powershell

```
cd c:\repos\myproject
```

run

```
npm install @angular/cli@9
```

wait for the result

```
ng update @angular/core@9
```

wait for the result, should be a successful result.

to be sure from the version, run

```
ng --version
```

Answer (score 0):

The angular cli provides a command for that, is `npx ng update`.